# attr = x.y.z if x.y else None gives AttributeError

Tags: python, attributeerror

I wondered what's the best method to solve following error:

```
'tuple' object has no attribute 'z'
```

from following code:

```
output = (x.y.z if x.y else None)
```

is it enough to just do:

```
output = (x.y.z if x.y.z else None)
```

Or will this also cause an `AttributeError`?

Comment: *Any* form of `x.y.z` will cause that error. If you want to test whether an object has an attribute, do `hasattr(x.y, 'z')`.

Comment: what is `x`? (`x.y` seems to be a `tuple`)...

Answer (score 2):

Following the idea of ["Easier to ask for forgiveness then permission"](https://docs.python.org/3.9/glossary.html#term-eafp)

```py
try: 
    output = x.y.z
except AttributeError: 
    output = None
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`hasattr()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#hasattr). Here is a code you could use:

```py
>>> output = (x.y.z if hasattr(x.y, 'z') else None)
```

Comment: Of course, you could also just write `getattr(x.y, 'z', None)`…

Comment: @deceze Oh, never knew `getattr` takes a third argument.

Comment: Use of `hasattr` is generally discouraged. Use an exception handler instead. See: https://hynek.me/articles/hasattr/

Comment: and what if x doesn't have an attribute y?

Comment: @sg_sg94 Then you're better off with `try: output = x.y.z except AttributeError: output = None`.

Comment: @sg_sg94 Then raises a `AttributeError`

Comment: @deceze But wouldn't that be worse because even if there wasn't attribute `y`, it would still raise an error.

Comment: I don't understand the concern.

Comment: @deceze Shouldn't it be something like: `temp = x.y; try: output = temp.z except AttributeError: output = None`

Comment: Depends on what you want to achieve and what errors you want to catch or not catch.